# What's the difference between HDFS federation and a whole new HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, federation

I want to know the the difference between HDFS federation and a whole new HDFS cluster, should I use the federation or just build a whole new cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Federation/ViewFS would allow you to access a brand new NameNode (cluster) nameservice from an existing cluster or bridge two existing clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Generally federation is used when you have a very large cluster (1000+) and you're pushing the limits of what you can store in HDFS.  Federation allows you divide your namespace and maintain all your data in one HDFS instance.  Depending on how you're using your data, you might want to use federation or have multiple smaller Hadoop clusters and then use `distcp` when you need to transfer data between clusters.  For example, if your data is siloed then using multiple clusters would make sense.  If your data has grown beyond the memory of your NameNode, but you still want to run some analysis on it, then federation would make sense.

Twitter uses federation and mentions it in their blog [Hadoop filesystem at Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2015/hadoop-filesystem-at-twitter.html).  You can also read about [HDFS router-based federation](https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/hdfs-router-based-federation) by Íñigo Goiri from Microsoft and Chao Sun from Uber.